# GWT interaction with external standalone application

Tags: java, gwt, ipc

I work on a standalone Java application that is a command-and-control system for an assortment of hardware.  The C&C software basically runs from a command line, and controls the system hardware which is spread out all over the place.  It does not require a GUI to meet the business requirements.  I have written a small swing GUI just so I can see what the overall status is of the system, but again, that is not essential.

Going forward, we would like to have a Administrative web GUI with system status and something that would give a user some level of control over the hardware.  We were thinking that GWT might be a viable solution.  Our GWT app would have to have some sort of IPC with the C&C software.  I don't know how viable that is, I don't know that we want the C&C software bundled as a web app that has to run under application server.

I just don't have much experience with this.  I was thinking that the GWT client would interact through RPC with the GWT server, and the GWT server would have some sort of RPC (RMI???) with the C&C.

Comment: How much control you have over your C&C application? Can you embed a web server into it?

Comment: I have 100% control over the C&C software, I wrote every line of it.  Embedded webserver....thats interesting man, that's interesting....I never considered that, nor have I ever done that.  Options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by using Spring.  We have modified much of our Command and Control app to use Spring IoC, and then we used other Spring libraries to extend its functionality.  To interact with GWT, we exposed services and used httpInvokers to make calls from the GWT server code.

Of course, this meant we needed to use Spring with our GWT application too in order to make the http calls from the GWT server code.  But all is working.

Answer (score 1):

Another option you have is to run a Java Applet that can interact with both GWT (using JSNI) and with the OS. A simple example would be to open a common file in the user's home folder and read/write to that file (with the C&C app doing the same as well).

Answer (score 1):

You can embed embedded tomcat or Jetty into your application and let it run a simple servlet/JSP - based or GWT-based web UI. In fact, when you debug/run your GWT application from Eclipse, it starts in an embedded Tomcat instance.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have direct control on the client system with JavaScript (which GWT is based on). in your use-case that wouldn't even make sense, why using an external server for a website controlling a local program?

If you reverse this (the app server is running on the same system as the C&C software, and the web client is available from everywhere) than that would be possible, but that wouldn't have much to do with GWT. On the server you can write normal java code. GWT just would be used for the web GUI and the RPC-calls to the server.
The call to the C&C software from the app server could be realised with the following line (windows example):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\PathTo\\Program.exe")`

This function return a instance of class `Process` which provides an Input- and OutputStream to simulate user input and to read and process the programs output.

Please note that you lose platform independence with this method, because the parameter for `exec()` looks different for every OS.

**EDIT**
After re-reading your question, it would even make more sense to integrate the C&C software into the server code directly, as the comment on your question suggests. you need a application server to use GWT-RPC, not a webserver, but thats hairsplitting.
Informations on how GWT-RPC generally works can be found here: [(tutorial)](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html), [(detailed description)](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideRemoteProcedureCalls)